# update query not working php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a project and I'm suppose to update the another user's details using the `$_GET` method. My problem is that when user clicks on the id, it does go to edit page but when i change something and press the update button, it does not update. I'm not sure what am i doing wrong here.. I would really appreciate f someone can help me.

//Edit

My code is working now guys, I just changed the $_POST to $_REQUEST now and my form is updated.. Thank you all for helping me.. Thank you.. Here is my edited code.. I've taken out the oassword field, but i have a doubt.. Is using request safe?

```
<?php
include '../../connection.php';

$sid = $_REQUEST['sid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STU_ID='$sid'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $unm = $row["STU_UNAME"];
    $fnm = $row["STU_FNAME"];
    $lnm = $row["STU_LNAME"];
    $dob = $row["STU_DOB"];
    $add = $row["STU_ADD"];
    $tlp = $row["STU_PHONE"];
        $sem = $row["STU_SEM"];
        $img = $row["STU_IMG"];
        $sts = $row["STU_STATUS"];
        $cid = $row["CRS_ID"];
  }
}
else{
   $no = "0 result!";
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
//insert details in data

$sid = $_POST["sid"]; $snm = $_POST["snm"]; $fst = $_POST["fnm"]; $lst = $_POST["lnm"]; $sdb = $_POST["dob"]; 
$sad = $_POST["add"]; $shp = $_POST["tlp"]; $stt = $_POST["sts"]; $sem = $_POST["sem"]; $cid = $_POST["cid"];

$sql = "UPDATE STUDENT SET 
        STU_ID='$sid', STU_UNAME='$snm', STU_FNAME= '$fst', STU_LNAME='$lst', STU_DOB='$sdb', STU_ADD='$sad', STU_PHONE='$shp', 
        STU_STATUS='$stt', STU_SEM='$sem', CRS_ID = '$cid' WHERE STU_ID='$sid'";

 //check if data is updated
 if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    header("Location: searchStudent.php");
 }
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
  }
}
?>
```

Here's my form code:

```
<form class="contact_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<ul>
   <li>
        <h2>Edit Students Details</h2>
        <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
   </li>
   <li>
        <label for="id">Student ID: </label>
        <input type="text" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sid;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="name">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="snm" value="<?php echo $unm;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="name">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fnm" value="<?php echo $fnm;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="name">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lnm" value="<?php echo $lnm;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="dob">Date of Birth: </label>
    <input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="add">Address: </label>
    <textarea name="add" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $add;?></textarea>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="tlp">Phone: </label>
    <input type="text" name="tlp" value="<?php echo $tlp;?>"/>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="sts">Status: </label>
    <select name="sts">
        <option selected><?php echo $sts;?></option>
        <option value="FULLTIME">FULL TIME</option>
        <option value="PARTTIME">PART TIME</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="sem">Semester: </label>
    <select name="sem">
        <option selected><?php echo $sem;?></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label for="crs">Course: </label>
    <select name="cid">
        <option selected><?php echo $cid;?></option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="DBM">DBM</option>
        <option value="DIT">DIT</option>
        <option value="DTM">DTM</option>
        <option value="FIS">FIS</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <button class="submit" type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Post your error message too

Comment: echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd there is no error message. But when i update it replacing the $_GET with an id, it update perfectly, it only doesn't update when i put the $_GET..

Comment: If your form method is GET then you must be go with $_GET only OR you can change your form method 'GET' to 'POST' and replace  `$id = $_POST['id'];` at top of your code.

Comment: since its working perfectly when passing an ID manually it means code is working for updation .. the problem is only in $_GET, so check for url if it contains parameters like (url?id=someid) or try replacing $id = $_GET['id']; with echo $id = $_GET['id']; and see if it prints the ID..

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if face else.

Comment: `echo $pwd;` -- is a really bad idea. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure your form method is POST*

Try this code:

```
<?php
include '../../connection.php';
//
 $id = $_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE STU_ID='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $unm = $row["STU_UNAME"];
    $fnm = $row["STU_FNAME"];
    $lnm = $row["STU_LNAME"];
    $pwd = $row["STU_PWD"];
    $dob = $row["STU_DOB"];
    $add = $row["STU_ADD"];
    $tlp = $row["STU_PHONE"];
    $sem = $row["STU_SEM"];
    $img = $row["STU_IMG"];
    $sts = $row["STU_STATUS"];
    $cid = $row["CRS_ID"];
  }
}
else{
    $no = "0 result!";
}


$pwdErr = $cpwdErr= "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   if($_POST["pwd"] == $_POST["cpwd"]){
     if(strlen($_POST["pwd"])>8){
    //insert details in data

    $sid = $_POST["sid"]; $pwd = $_POST["pwd"]; $snm = $_POST["snm"]; $fst = $_POST["fnm"]; $lst = $_POST["lnm"];
    $sdb = $_POST["dob"]; $sad = $_POST["add"]; $shp = $_POST["tlp"]; $stt = $_POST["sts"]; $sem = $_POST["sem"];
    $cid = $_POST["cid"];

    $sql = "UPDATE STUDENT SET 
            STU_ID='$sid', STU_PWD='$pwd', STU_UNAME='$snm', STU_FNAME= '$fst', STU_LNAME='$lst', STU_DOB='$sdb', STU_ADD='$sad', STU_PHONE='$shp', 
            STU_STATUS='$stt', STU_SEM='$sem', CRS_ID = '$cid' WHERE STU_ID='$id'";

        //check if data is updated
        if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
            header("Location: searchStudent.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
        }
    }
    else{
        $pwdErr = "Invalid/Password must be more than 8 characters!";
    }
}
else{
    $cpwdErr = "Password not same!";
  }
}
?>
```

Get ride for how to use prepare statement with example [here](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/).

Hope this help you well!

Comment: i did like you said and changed it, but now the problem is that, when the user clicks the id, it goes to edit page but does not show the user's details.. This is my code for when the user clicks the edit link <a href="editStudent.php?id='.$row['STU_ID'].'">Edit</a> and then it goes to the update page

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_POST); exit;`. Just check and compare it with your update query values.

Comment: Did you changed GET to POST of your form method attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is your are using POST in your form but getting its value with get change $_get with $_POST

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: that was before, now i have changed my code with $_POST['id']

Comment: it should be this

`$id = $_POST['sid'];`

Comment: since input name for student is 'sid'

Answer (score 0):

well problem is that id you are posting is "sid" but you are using just "id" like `$_POST['id']` instead of `$_POST['sid']`. so use this -

```
$id = $_POST['sid'];
```

instead of -

```
$id = $_POST['id']
```